# Shapely parallel_offset returning an empty list

Tags: python, shapely

I have a LineString and when I try to create a right parallel line with parallel_offset I get an empty list. What am I doing wrong?  The code is as follow:

```
Line_ = LineString([Point(-131241, 5700864), Point(-130215, 5700016.609604769), Point(-129200, 5699155), Point(-128256, 5698218), Point(-127481, 5697139), Point(-126943, 5695927), Point(-126662, 5694629), Point(-126617, 5693300), Point(-126815, 5691987), Point(-127147, 5690699)])
print(Line_.parallel_offset(15000, 'right'))
LINESTRING EMPTY
```

While if I use parallel_offset to calculate the left parallel line of the same LineString I get the expected result:

```
Line_ = LineString([Point(-131241, 5700864), Point(-130215, 5700016.609604769), Point(-129200, 5699155), Point(-128256, 5698218), Point(-127481, 5697139), Point(-126943, 5695927), Point(-126662, 5694629), Point(-126617, 5693300), Point(-126815, 5691987), Point(-127147, 5690699)])
print(Line_.parallel_offset(15000, 'left'))
LINESTRING (-121688.949663129 5712429.393826493, -120662.949663129 5711582.003431262, -120507.734800415 5711452.037115139, -119492.734800415 5710590.42751037, -118632.9431239474 5709800.999670218, -117688.9431239474 5708863.999670218, -116841.5246323321 5707949.893550635, -116072.9273087647 5706968.585111869, -115297.9273087647 5705889.585111869, -114466.0962164286 5704596.364112364, -113771.0294072872 5703224.779025478, -113233.0294072872 5702012.779025478, -112683.2909290381 5700581.105414742, -112282.6077144392 5699100.782921605, -112001.6077144392 5697802.782921605, -111776.287252372 5696477.122289002, -111670.5913831028 5695136.609772582, -111625.5913831028 5693807.609772582, -111642.1468335366 5692431.799192087, -111784.6992899678 5691063.293571526, -111982.6992899678 5689750.293571526, -112289.7845017582 5688242.922713186, -112621.7845017582 5686954.922713186)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not doing anything wrong. Left and right are determined by following the direction of the line. This method may sometimes return `EMPTY` geometry for curved lines if offset value is huge. If you use distance values less than ~9650 for this line, you will understand clearly what I mean.

[image]

Review samples in [Documentation](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/latest/manual.html#object.parallel_offset).