# Drawing perpendicular line from existing line in Python

Tags: python, gdal, shapefile, shapely

I want to draw a perpendicular line from the mid point of another line. For this, I could not find any function or straightforward approach.

The method I am following is, first I am creating offsets of the line on both left and right sides first with the `parallel_offset` function of `shapely` and then finding the mid point of the offset lines and connecting those. This is based on [this question post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57065080/draw-perpendicular-line-of-fixed-length-at-a-point-of-another-line) but for GeoPandas data frame data.

The problem I am facing in this is, that for some lines if I am taking a larger offset distance, it is creating an empty line string for the offset. As explained in [Shapely parallel_offset returning an empty list](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/374268), I guess the error is occurring as the offset is vanishing at a certain distance which depends on the curvature of the original line.

I am thinking there must be a way to draw a perpendicular line from another line at any point in Python which can be drawn straightway.

How do I solve this issue?

Comment: The "other line" is a simple line consisting of two vertices?

Comment: Please [Edit] the Question to be more specific. If the units are angular (geographic), a perpendicular line isn't actually perpendicular (or even straight).

Answer (score 1):

Your linked answer can be used for your problem.

In this case Geopandas is just a way to read and write a shapefile. Geopandas geometries are shapely geometries so you can apply the same logic.

Create a function which creates a parallel line, find its centroid then draw a line from your original lines centroid to the parallel lines centroid:

```
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import LineString

df = gpd.read_file(r'/home/bera/Desktop/GIStest/AAAAAAAAAAAAA.shp')

def giveline(linestring, distance):
    "From a input shapely linestring, return a perpendicular linestring with the length equal to intput distance"
    pline = linestring.parallel_offset(distance=distance)
    return LineString([linestring.centroid, pline.centroid])

df['perpline'] = df.apply(lambda x: giveline(linestring=x.geometry, distance=200), axis=1) #Create a column of perpendicular line geometries
df2 = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df, geometry=df['perpline'], crs="EPSG:3006") #Use this to create a new dataframe
df2 = df2[['geometry']]

df2.to_file(r'/home/bera/Desktop/GIStest/BBBBB.shp')
```

[image]

Comment: As I have mentioned in the question, this approach is returning a empty `LineString` when the curve of line is too high and/or the offset distance is high.